# authorized_keys in non standard place

Tags: sshd, chroot, key-authentication

authorized_keys in usualy put under .ssh in one HOME's directory.

I want to put it in a non standard place like `/etc/AK/authorized_keys.archemar`

I set up sshd_config with a match rule

```
Match user archemar
        ChrootDirectory /exploit/X25
        AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/AK/authorized_keys.%u
        PasswordAuthentication no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0002
        PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

however I cannot login without password, sshd report an error.

```
sshd[] Failed publickey for archemar from ... port 41154 ssh2: RSA SHA256:...
```

command is either `sftp` or `ssh`

```
sftp -i archemar archemar@localhost
ssh -i archemar -l archemar localhost
```

public key work fine when authorized_keys is in usual place.

file authorisation is

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  802 Oct 24 10:51 authorized_keys.archemar
```

directory `/etc/AK` is `drwx------`

what am I missing ?
Is this a `chroot` issue ?

---

- OS is Suse 12.4,
- I did put section at the end of `sshd_config` and restart,
- selinux is disabled.

Comment: Enable debugging at server side and try to see what configuration is being applied to the session. Did you put the user specific configuration at the bottom of the sshd configuration? Did you restart sshd to set the new configuration active?

Comment: The authorized_keys file mode should be 600 and owned by the user

Comment: The `ssh -i` flag is looking for a file path, that is what looks to be failing.  If you do not pass `-i`, then it should use your `AuthorizedKeysFile` from `ssh_config`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to comply to the expectations on the permissions that sshd imposes:

- The directory where the public keys reside should be at least executable by all.

  ```bash
  chmod 711 /etc/AK
  chown root:root /etc/AK
  ```
- The public keys need to be owned by their user, these permissions work for me:

  ```bash
  chown archemar:root /etc/AK/authorized_keys.archemar
  chmod 640 /etc/AK/authorized_keys.archemar
  ```