# How can I provide the authorized_keys path in sshd that allows normal users, system users, and a root user?

Tags: ssh, openssh

Is it possible to set the `AuthorizedKeysFile` setting explicitly such that it covers the following cases:

1. standard user under `/home/%u/.ssh/authorized_keys`
2. system user under `/var/lib/%u/.ssh/authorized_keys`
3. root user under `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

My question is, is there a variable that contains the user directory as specified in the [Name Service Switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch)?

Comment: Have you tried naming multiple paths in this option?

Comment: `man` on my Debian says by default it uses two paths anyways. But I'd also think `~` is resolved based on `/etc/passwd` (unless defined otherwise in `nsswitch.conf`. Why is it searching in `/root` though? Are you ssh-ing as root?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have indicated that you would accept using the the user's home directory to be used as the base for `.ssh/` -  whether the user is a real user, system user or root.

I'm inferring this from your question:

> I tried to solve this by changing my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to
>
> ```
> AuthorizedKeysFile ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
> ```
>
> This failed, because `sshd` was checking `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

If you take a quick look at [the manual for `sshd_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) you will see this:

> #### AuthorizedKeysFile
>
> Specifies the file that contains the public keys that can be used for user authentication. AuthorizedKeysFile may contain tokens of the form %T which are substituted during connection setup. The following tokens are defined: %% is replaced by a literal '%', **%h is replaced by the home directory of the user being authenticated**, and %u is replaced by the username of that user. After expansion, AuthorizedKeysFile is taken to be an absolute path or one relative to the user's home directory. The default is ''.ssh/authorized_keys''.

---

In my default setup I have have a line commented out:

```
# AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This means that (at least for Ubuntu and Debian distributions of OpenSSH) you are actually asking for the default configuration!  That may be as good a reason as any for the down-votes.

Comment: Where did you get that I didnt read the manual. I certainly did! I even mention that in the content. I appreciate the answer either way.

Comment: @JonathanKomar It is possible your manual is different to mine... *that does happen*.  But assuming it doesn't then I have quoted the paragraph that indicates that `%h` and not `~` should have been used.  The fact you tried `~` and never `%h` suggests you didn't read, or perhaps missed something.  Please don't be offended I have not down voted, only given a hint as to other's reasoning.

Comment: Just noted an unfair assumption that I did not read the manual. It says clearly that `%h` represents the user’s home dir. I understood that it represents`/home/user`. Of course, that is not the case. In hindsight, it was a mistake on my part to not understand that important sentence.

Comment: @JonathanKomar don't let it bother you too much.  I totally agree down-votes should be followed up with comments.

Answer (score 5):

as per @Tomasz, you can use match User

```
# no match rule
AuthorizedKeysFile /home/%u/.ssh/authorized_keys

match User foo
    AuthorizedKeysFile /special/authorized_keys.%u

match Group git
    /var/lib/%u/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

using more generic users first.

see man `ssh_config` or man `sshd_config`

(on a side note, I couldn't make it to work on sles12 with chroot)

Comment: see my question here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548506/authorized-keys-in-non-standard-place